# Proving $\sqrt2$ is irrational directly (not by contradiciton)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm searchiing for another efficient strategy to prove that a given number is irrational other than the contradiction one, for example:

Let $\sqrt 2=p/q$ (assuming p/q is irreducible)

Therefore $2q^2=p^2$ therefore $p=2k$ where $k\in N$

Thus $q^2=2k^2$ therefore $q$ is even.

But this contradicts our assumption that p/q is irreducible.

Comment: You will not find an elementary method that does what you seek, because "irrational" is defined as "not rational", so to prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational you need to verify that it is not any of the possible rationals.   By far the simplest way to do this is contradiction.

Comment: What are the other ways please?

Comment: Not all proofs of this kind need a contradiction. Sometimes we are lucky enough to build a constructive proof, showing that the distance of $x$ to any rational is always bigger than zero. As an example, we can show $\left|\sqrt 2 -\dfrac pq\right|\gt \dfrac{1}{2q^2}$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @IanMateus Could you provide more details please :) ?

Comment: Keyword : Diophantine approximation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One "direct" proof  $\sqrt{2} \ne p/q\in\Bbb Q\, $ is quantitative: show $\,|p/q - \sqrt{2}| \ge f(q),\,$ e.g. as below

$$ \left| \dfrac{p}q - \sqrt{2} \right| = \left| \dfrac{p-\sqrt{2}q}{q}\right| = \left|\dfrac{p^2-2q^2 }{q(p+\sqrt{2}q)}\right|\ge \dfrac{1}{q^2(p/q+\sqrt{2})} \ge \dfrac{1}{3q^2}\ \ {\rm if}\ \ \dfrac{p}q \le 3-\sqrt{2}$$

Alternatively one may prove that a real number is irrational by showing that it has too many good rational approximations.  If $\alpha\,$ is irrational then the convergents $\,p_n/q_n\,$ of its continued fraction expansion yield **infinitely** many "good" approximants $\,p/q\,$ satisfying
$$\left| \dfrac{p}{q} -\alpha\right| \,<\, \dfrac{1}{q^2}\tag{1}$$
But for rationals $\,a/b$ $$ {\left| \dfrac{p}q - \dfrac{a}b\right|\, =\, \dfrac{\left| bp-aq\right|}{bq} \ge \dfrac{1}{bq} > \dfrac{1}{q^2}\ \ {\rm if}\ \ q > b}$$

since  $\ q > b\,\Rightarrow\, \frac{1}b > \frac{1}q\,\Rightarrow\, \frac{1}{bq} > \frac{1}{q^2}.\ $  Thus rationals $ a/b$ have only **finitely** many rational approximants $\,p/q,$  that are good, i.e. satisfy $(1),$ since they must have $\,q \le b.$

To learn more about this approach look up the [Thue-Siegel-Roth Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem)

Comment: Impressive! Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: In the first displayed line, you assumed that $p^2-2q^2\ne 0$. This can be proved, say by the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @André  Right, the first approach is meant as a way to finish the standard proof in a *constructive* manner, i.e. avoiding proof by contradiction or the law of the excluded middle (as the OP requested). If memory serves correct, that is one method employed by constructivist schools, e.g. Bishop.